# IBM Worklight - Sencha Touch app shows white screen

Tags: sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new for sencha touch, so to start with it , I downloaded a (sencha touch + worklight) project from given [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2830-439413-14867203-380696/Sencha2DemoProj.zip) and imported in eclipse . it is getting build and running perfectly when I run it in worklight console i.e localhost:8080/console but when I run it in android emulator it shows blank white screen . and gives error, i have attached [log file here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/servlet/JiveServlet/download/2830-466828-14924769-384193/Sencha2DemoProj%20log.txt) apart from this even I tried few more project all of them shows blank white screen.

I tried to run it in different AVD i.e Android 2.1, 2.2 , 2.3 but I get same problem.
I don`t know where is the problem whether in Worklight or Sencha Touch.

Comment: hi friend i have not worked out in snecha but i have some experience in Worklight+jquery. In logcat i found 01-03 12:30:57.137: D/CordovaLog(416): file:///data/data/com.Sencha2Demo/files/www/default/js/Sencha2Demo.js: Line 12 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: **Ext**. I.e EXT is variable not defined. Solution -> whether its Snecha library variable or u need to define it

Comment: @RED.Skull If the variable was not defined, wouldn't that mean it should crash when running on the console as well? I would try running it on an actual device, not the emulator. Also, apart from the log that prints in the screen, check out the Android LogCat and the actual server's log file to see if you pick up on anything else that might give you a clue.

Comment: @Ralph Pina in Android Log cat it is only showing that ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext and in server log there is no error. i downloaded another application from IBM website ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/WorklightStarter_Sencha.zip this one is working very well on android emulator as well as worklight console so i don't understand why this is working and other apps are not working. please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: @user1163283 Do you have a post in developerWorks? If so, give me the URL, maybe you can post a sample of your project. There is obviously something that you are changing that is causing this issue.

Comment: @Ralph Pina Yes I had posted a question on IBM developerWorks this is url https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=466828

Comment: What version of Worklight are you using?
The example in your ZIP file was written to an older version of Worklight.
There are other examples of Worklight with Sencha Touch, did you try them (ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/WorklightStarter_Sencha.zip)?

Comment: @ravidor I have tried this example and it is working perfectly everywhere e.g. on worklight console, simulator, and emulator but when I create any new application, that does not work in emulator and if you want to see log cat that I have attached above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Sencha edition of Worklight Starter has been recently re-written for Worklight 6.0.

You can try this new version from this location: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/WorklightStarter_Sencha.zip

See if that helps guiding you instead of the very oudated projects you have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

After running into this same issue myself and finally working out how to solve it, I thought I'd share.

You need to Deploy the Worklight Adapter before you build and test your project.

Here is how:

1. Open WorklightStarter_Sencha project in Eclipse, open the adapters folder and highlight the WorklightStarterAdapter folder.
2. From the menu bar select Run -> Run As -> Deploy Worklight Adapter.
3. Now build and deploy your project.